# Adding legends and y-axis value on sparkline bar charts

Tags: jquery, plot, sparklines

I was working on **[sparklines bar graph](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-docs)**. Until now I am able to draw a simple bar graph, here is the Jquery code:

```
values = [0,8, 15, 10, 50, 25, 35, 70];
$('.sparkline').sparkline(values, {
    type: 'bar',
    height: '200px',
    barWidth: 20,
    barSpacing: 10,
    barColor: '#56aaff',
    zeroColor: '#000000',
    enableTagOptions: true,
    tagValuesAttribute: 'data-values',
    colorMap: ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "#f2f2f2", "maroon", "pink"]

});
```

HTML

```
<p>
<span class="sparkline">Loading...</span>
</p>
```

Please refer my code at **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ERfgA/49/)** .

Now I want to add legends name as well as value of y-axis on each of the bar as shown below.

[image]

sun,mon,tue are legends and the value on white color at the top of the bars are y-axis value.

But I am not able to achieve it.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The more I could do is pointing you to sparkline's FAQ:
http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-faq

> Frequently Asked Questions
>
> Why are there no axis labels/markers?
>
> Sparklines are intended to be small enough to fit alongside a line of
>   text, to give a quick impression of a trend or pattern and thus don't
>   have the paraphernalia of full sized charts. As of version 2.0 you can
>   mouse over the sparklines to see the underlying data.