# Keep Sparkline Tooltips from Hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, sparklines

Creating Sparkline line graphs. 
http://jsfiddle.net/gwatts/PfzXg/

```
// Draw a sparkline for the #sparkline element
$('.sparkline').sparkline(values, {
    type: "line",
    tooltipSuffix: " widgets"
});
```

The jFiddle example is not the best, but I think it illustrates the point. 
The default behavior is to have the tooltips appear once the mouse hovers over the value. The "5 widgets" tooltip appears when you hover over the point.

Is it possible to have the tooltip always appear?
I wanted to make a graph that is bigger and has static data labels (tooltips), but I don't see any mention of it in the documentation. 
https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781125/adding-legends-and-y-axis-value-on-sparkline-bar-charts) question could be response to yours.

here the answer:

http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-faq

> Frequently Asked Questions
>
> Why are there no axis labels/markers?
>
> Sparklines are intended to be small enough to fit alongside a line of text, to give a quick impression of a trend or pattern and thus don't have the paraphernalia of full sized charts. As of version 2.0 you can mouse over the sparklines to see the underlying data.

It is necessary use Sparkline library in your project?, if you want a big chart and labels you have other option like http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/.

Comment: Not really necessary. Was trying to use these graphs because they are very lightweight and being placed on a page that is not so lightweight. Not looking a big chart. Typically I just use HighCharts, but wanted to see what was possible with SparkLine. 

Will see if anyone else replies before I mark this as the answer. Thanks!